# Perl Cygwin fun. Module is loaded, but not being found by the program

Tags: perl, cygwin, perl-module

Okay a few rules:

- No, I cannot install Strawberry Perl on this system. I have to use Cygwin.
- This is Perl 5.8.7. I cannot update it.
- This is not my system. This is a customer's system, and I cannot modify it to my hearts content.

Now, we've gotten that out of the way...

I have installed `Spreadsheet::Read`, `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`, and `Spreadsheet::XLSX` on this system. This installed a little Perl script called `xlscat`. We've done this before on a development box and the UAT box. Now this is the production box.

I am getting the following error:

```
Parser for XLSX is not installed at /usr/bin/xlscat line 185
```

I've traced this to `Spreadsheet::Read`. The relevant code is:

```
my @parsers = (
    [ csv       => "Text::CSV_XS"               ],
    [ csv       => "Text::CSV_PP"               ], # Version 1.05 and up
    [ csv       => "Text::CSV"                  ], # Version 1.00 and up
    [ ods       => "Spreadsheet::ReadSXC"       ],
    [ sxc       => "Spreadsheet::ReadSXC"       ],
    [ xls       => "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel"    ],
    [ xlsx      => "Spreadsheet::XLSX"          ],
    [ prl       => "Spreadsheet::Perl"          ],

    # Helper modules
    [ ios       => "IO::Scalar"                 ],
    );
my %can = map { $_->[0] => 0 } @parsers;
for (@parsers) {
    my ($flag, $mod) = @$_;
    print STDERR qq(DEBUG: Flag = "$flag" Mod = "$mod"\n);
    $can{$flag} and next;
    eval "require $mod; \$can{\$flag} = '$mod'";
    }
print STDERR Dumper(\%can); #DEBUG:
```

The lines that start contain the string `DEBUG:` are mine.

A dump of `@parsers` shows that everything is loaded correctly. The first debug prints out the value of `$flag` and `$mod` correctly.

The problem seems to come from the `eval` statement. From what I can see, it runs `require` against a module, and then sets the `$can{$flag}` variable to `$mod` if the require succeeds. Apparently, `require Spreadsheet::XLSX` fails. Here's the relevant output from my debug statements:

```
DEBUG: Flag = "csv" Mod = "Text::CSV_XS"
DEBUG: Flag = "csv" Mod = "Text::CSV_PP"
DEBUG: Flag = "csv" Mod = "Text::CSV"
DEBUG: Flag = "ods" Mod = "Spreadsheet::ReadSXC"
DEBUG: Flag = "sxc" Mod = "Spreadsheet::ReadSXC"
DEBUG: Flag = "xls" Mod = "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel"
DEBUG: Flag = "xlsx" Mod = "Spreadsheet::XLSX"
DEBUG: Flag = "prl" Mod = "Spreadsheet::Perl"
DEBUG: Flag = "ios" Mod = "IO::Scalar"
$VAR1 = {
      'csv' => 'Text::CSV_XS',
      'sxc' => 0,
      'xlsx' => 0,
      'xls' => 'Spreadsheet::ParseExcel',
      'ios' => 'IO::Scalar',
      'prl' => 0,
      'ods' => 0
    };
```

Hmmm... Maybe the module isn't installed?

```
$ perldoc -l Spreadsheet::XLSX
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm
```

It shows up in `perldoc`. Let's write a quick test program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Spreadsheet::XLSX;

print "It works\n";
```

And...

```
$ ./test.pl
DEBUG: Flag = "csv" Mod = "Text::CSV_XS"
DEBUG: Flag = "csv" Mod = "Text::CSV_PP"
DEBUG: Flag = "csv" Mod = "Text::CSV"
DEBUG: Flag = "ods" Mod = "Spreadsheet::ReadSXC"
DEBUG: Flag = "sxc" Mod = "Spreadsheet::ReadSXC"
DEBUG: Flag = "xls" Mod = "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel"
DEBUG: Flag = "xlsx" Mod = "Spreadsheet::XLSX"
DEBUG: Flag = "prl" Mod = "Spreadsheet::Perl"
DEBUG: Flag = "ios" Mod = "IO::Scalar"
$VAR1 = {
          'csv' => 'Text::CSV_XS',
          'sxc' => 0,
          'xlsx' => 0,
          'xls' => 'Spreadsheet::ParseExcel',
          'ios' => 'IO::Scalar',
          'prl' => 0,
          'ods' => 0
        };
It works
```

I can pick up `Spreadsheet::XLSX` via the `use Spreadsheet::XLSX` in my test program, yet the `require` in `Spreadsheet::Read` doesn't seem to see it.

Why?

---

## Addendum

> What do you get if you print Dumper( \%INC ) ? – friedo 2 mins ago

I actually did one better. I added the following line in the loop:

```
require $mod if ($mod eq "Spreadsheet::XLSX"); #DEBUG
```

And that produced the error message:

```
Can't locate Spreadsheet::XLSX in @INC (@INC contains:
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/cygwin /usr/lib/perl5/5.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/cygwin
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/cygwin
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/cygwin
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/cygwin
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 .) at 
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/Spreadsheet/Read.pm line 57.
Compilation failed in require at ./test.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./test.pl line 3.
```

(**NOTE**: I reformatted the output, so it wouldn't be 1000+ characters long, and it's easier to see the `@INC` path).

The module is in `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm`.

Oh, take a look at this too:

```
$ pwd
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/Spreadsheet

$ ls -la
total 152
drwxr-xr-x+  4 phalder   Domain Users      0 Nov  1 21:51 .
drwxrwxrw-+ 11 twinborne Users             0 Nov  1 22:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x+  3 phalder   Domain Users      0 Nov  1 20:48 ParseExcel
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phalder   Domain Users 107773 Apr  6  2011 ParseExcel.pm
-rwxrwxrwx   1 phalder   Domain Users  29142 Nov  2 12:53 Read.pm
drwxr-xr-x+  2 phalder   Domain Users      0 Nov  1 21:51 XLSX
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phalder   Domain Users   8411 May 16  2010 XLSX.pm

$ ls -la XLSX
total 48
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 phalder Domain Users     0 Nov  1 21:51 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 4 phalder Domain Users     0 Nov  1 21:51 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 phalder Domain Users  5487 May 16  2010 Fmt2007.pm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 phalder Domain Users 37046 May 16  2010 Utility2007.pm
```

The permissions seem okay.

---

## Another Addendum:

When I did a CPAN reinstall, I got this:

```
Result: PASS
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/cygwin/auto/Spreadsheet/Read'
Do not have write permissions on     
'/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/cygwin/auto/Spreadsheet/Read'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/Spreadsheet/Read.pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/Spreadsheet.Read.3pm
make: *** [pure_site_install] Error 255
   /usr/bin/make install  -- NOT OK
```

Oops! I didn't check the permission of the `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/cygwin` directory tree.

Did a `chmod -R a+rx *` on the whole `/usr/lib/perl5` directory. We'll see if it works again.

Comment: What do you get if you `print Dumper( \%INC )` ?

Comment: @friedo - See my Addendum at the bottom of the post. You'll see that `@INC` is fine and so are the file permissions.

Comment: `require $mod` does not do what you think it does. See `perldoc -f require`. You need `eval "require $mod"`

Comment: What is in `$@` after the `eval "require $mod ..."` statement?

Comment: @SinanÜnür - What do you mean _does not do what you think it does?_ Where do I need `eval "$require $mod`? The `Spreadsheet::Read` already does an eval. I did it without the `eval`, so I can see the error.

Comment: @mod - I've decided to reinstall the Spreadsheet modules via `cpan` again and see if the problem goes away. If I have the same issues, I'll check the value of both `@INC` and `%INC`.

Comment: If `$mod` contains the string `Spreadsheet::XLSX`, then `require $mod` looks for the file `Spreadsheet::XLSX`, not for `Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm`. That is why you need `eval "require $mod"`.

Comment: Ah. I see. You're right. I can't use a variable or quotes. Well, at least we see what `@INC` equals. I'm doing a reinstall and see what happens. If that doesn't work, I'll modify that statement to remove `$mod` and do a direct `require Spreadsheet::XLSX`.

Comment: Another Addendum: I think I found the issue...

Comment: I found the issue. See the answer **Found the Problem**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Found the Problem

I took a slightly different tact. I modified `Spreadsheet::Read` to print out `$@` after the `eval`. That way, I could see what error it was getting. Here's the results:

```
$ ./test.pl
DEBUG: ""DEBUG: "Can't locate Spreadsheet/ReadSXC.pm in @INC
(@INC contains:
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/cygwin
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/cygwin
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/cygwin
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/cygwin
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/cygwin
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 .) at (eval 8) line 1.
"DEBUG: "Can't locate Spreadsheet/ReadSXC.pm in @INC
(@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/cygwin [...]) at (eval 9) line 1.
"DEBUG: ""DEBUG: "Can't locate Compress/Raw/Zlib.pm in @INC
(@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/cygwin [...]) at (eval 15) line 1.
"DEBUG: "Can't locate Spreadsheet/Perl.pm in @INC
(@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/cygwin [...]) at (eval 18) line 1.
```

Did you see that? The problem isn't `Spreadsheet::XLSX`, but `Compress::Raw::Zlib`. I set the entire permissions on `/usr/lib/perl` to `777`, and then installed `Compress::Raw::Zlib` and `Spreadsheet::ReadSXC`.

This must have been a problem when these modules were initially installed. I wasn't the one doing the cpan install, but helping the person over the phone, so I didn't get a chance to see these errors if they popped up. CPAN tends to be really, really noisy, and I've learned to catch the random error message as CPAN runs by.

The problem may have been `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/cygwin` not having the correct permissions all along.

The program now works.

Thanks for all of your help. Somehow, it lead me down the right trail.